# TCP client server

Tags: java, serialization, tcp

I have a question on TCP client / server network. Im trying to create a chat application. My plan is for the client to send Conversation objects across the network (object has a String username state and a String currentMessage state). My question is, should i be creating a new object each time i send a message? i.e call the Conversation class constructor each  time i want to send a new message? or should i be just updating the currentMessage state?? I have this question because at the moment, i have it just updating the state and here is what happens:

The currentMessage state updates fine on the client side, but when i send the Conversation object across the network and try to retrieve the currentMessage state on the other side i keep getting the original state value. Why is this? The server keeps refering to the original message value i sent the first time??

PS I dont want to be posting reams of code so im hoping someone might have a general idea what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you are using an ObjectOutputStream or something similar?

Had this problem my self some time ago. When you send the first time it works fine, but after that it doesnt update properly.

This is because the stream saves the object state, and if it is sent again it doesnt update.
You need to use the [reset()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) method after you received an object to make it update again.

Comment: Thanks, yes i believe this is the solution i need :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the ObjectOutputStream class to serialize your Conversation object?  If so, it will cache classes that you've already written to the stream, so even when you change the values client-side, every time you write that object, it will send a pointer to that object, saving a great deal of time and bandwidth.  Unfortunately, that's not always your goal, so you're left with have two choices:

- Reset the stream.  From the JavaDoc:

> Reset will disregard the state of any objects already written to the
>   stream. The state is reset to be the same as a new ObjectOutputStream.
>   The current point in the stream is marked as reset so the
>   corresponding ObjectInputStream will be reset at the same point.
>   Objects previously written to the stream will not be refered to as
>   already being in the stream. They will be written to the stream again.

You can read a great article about this [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue088.html).

- Create new instances of your Conversation object, as you suggested.

I personally find it cleaner to create new objects rather than be resetting the stream before (or after) every write, however if you're in a situation where the allocation of your object is rather large and you're only changing a couple fields between network writes, it may be better to reset the stream.

This kind of optimization, however, is probably best put off until later in your project when you can do some real profiling to see which works better for you.  My advice is to pick whichever you're most comfortable with and move forward until you're at a point that optimization matters.  Always remember, premature optimization is the bane of good programming! : )

Comment: Hi matthew, thanks for reply..Yes im using serialization..Originally i had my code sending new objects each time but i thought it was a bit wasteful and changed it to just updating the message state. So say if i were updating a vector instead of a string, which is what i initially wanted to do, how will this work..You see, i want to write a polling mechanism, where the clients is going to ask for the latest messages posted to the server (this will consist of a vector of strings)..How will i send this vector across the network?

Comment: i.e if i create a new object each time the Vector is just going to get reset to a new Vector each time.. I dont want that, i want the full vector of conversation strings to be sent from the server back to the client..Im not too sure if i made that clear enough to understand..

Comment: i believe my question is : How do i create a new object but keep the same fully populated Vector?  Is that even possible? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Do you have a Vector of objects you want to send?  In that case, I'd keep the same Vector, add items to it, then send each object, instead of the whole vector.  You can then clear the Vector, refill it, and re-iterate through it to send any new objects that it might have.

Comment: Quick note: Vector has been replaced by classes that implements the List interface (LinkedList, ArrayList, etc.), which should be used in all new code.

Comment: Hi Matthew..It seems we must be in two different time zones! I seem to have my code working now..However, i was wondering could you explain to me exactly what reset does, because from what i can see on the serverSide: The server is receving different Client objects but yet the object has all the vectorElements that the last object had..i.e the new object remembers the last objects states..but how can that be, if it is a different object?? i hope im making sense here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [flyweight design pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

Basically you can have an object that is always the same. You wrap it in another object. 
In your case the object you send will be the same every time. The only thing you change is the text.

While I'm not sure how your code works, the way I see it is, **(1)** create a new object to send every time or **(2)** create one and keep setting different text to send in it (which is kinda like flyweight).

The former way, you can preallocate a large list of these envelopes, and consume them one by one as you send the message. This will improve performance.

As for your other question, I agree w Matt and Hasslam. What you're sending is probably cached so you need to refresh it, or rather let Java know it has been changed.